# Query page in wordpress by slug/ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show my page content using id or slug. I managed to do this in some other WP theme but for some reason its not working this time...

I want to show title, excerpt and featured image

This is my code:

```
<h1 class="text-center light-title"><?php echo the_title() ?></h1>
                            <span class="light-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
                            <?php 
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'center-block img-responsive')); // show featured image
                                } 
                            ?>
                                <?php 
                                    query_posts("page_id=222");
                                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
                                ?>
                            <?php //the_content() ?>
                                <?php
                                    endwhile; 
                                    wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
```

Comment: Move your `query_posts("page_id=222"); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()` above of the `the_tittle`. `the_title(), the_post_thumbnail(),the_content()` must be place inside the loop. On this `echo the_title()`, you should not use echo on `the_title()`, this is already displaying without echo.

Visit [codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what is failing, but the order of your code doesn't seem right. the_title() and the_excerpt() are normally **inside** the loop. Like this:

```
  <?php 
  query_posts("page_id=222");
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
  ?>
      <h1 class="text-center light-title"><?php echo the_title() ?></h1>
      <span class="light-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
              the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'center-block img-responsive')); // show featured image
            } 
      ?>
      <?php //the_content() ?>
  <?php
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts` will give you more control about the scope:

```
<?php 
  $page = new WP_Query("page_id=374");
  while ( $page->have_posts() ) : $page->the_post();
     the_content();
  endwhile;
?>
```